# pthread mutex not working, getting a random value each time

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I'm learning POSIX pthreads and while using a mutex I started getting a weird output.
Every time I run the code it outputs a random number while I expect it to output `0`. I checked the code and I could not figure out the reason why it happens so if can someone explain to me what is going wrong exactly it will be very appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int num = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void* add(void* args)
{
    int sign = *(int*) args;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        num += sign;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;
}


int main()
{
    pthread_t pool[1000];
    int plus = +1;
    int minus = -1;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);


    for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        pthread_create(&pool[i], NULL, add, &plus);

    for(int i = 500; i < 1000; i++)
        pthread_create(&pool[i], NULL, add, &minus);

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        pthread_join(pool[i], NULL);

    printf("%d", num);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Before you assume the mutex isn't working, try this endeavor with a reasonable thread count (say, 100, 50 each side). Depending on the platform, a thousand threads in a single process is a stretch. And since there is absolutely no error checking whatsoever in this code, you really don't know what the problem is. It may have nothing to do with the mutex. Those return values from pthread functions mean something; use them.

Comment: @WhozCraig You're right ! after adding error checking I noticed `pthread_create` fails after approximately 500 calls, I don't know the reason for this but when I reduced the thread count to 100 I noticed mutex work as expected. What I don't understand though is why does `pthread_create` fail after that number, I searched for the maximum number of threads per process and apparently its 2000 so I don't think its that. my platform is windows 10 if that helps.

Comment: @yxor What is the value of `errno` after `pthread_create()` fails?

Comment: @AndrewHenle its `12`, and the error string is `Not enough space`. I suspect it has something to do with some software limitation of the number of threads and not windows itself.

Comment: @yxor File a bug report.  [The proper `errno` value in that case should be `EAGAIN`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_create.html#tag_03_525_05).

Comment: The proper way to initialize a pthread_mutex_t.   `pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;`  There are a few other valid initialization values other than `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` However, this is the most commonly use initializer

Comment: OT: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. I.E. 100, 500, 1000.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: regarding this kind of statement:  `pthread_create(&pool[i], NULL, add, &plus);`  Always check (==0) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror( "pthread_create failed" )` so both the error message and the reason the system thinks the failure occurred to `stderr`

Comment: regarding: `pthread_t pool[1000];`  This should be written as: `pthread_t pool[1000] = {0};` so when calling `pthread_join()`, the code can skip those entries that were never the result of  a `pthread_create()`  so do not try to join non-existant threads

Comment: Note: most OSs are setup to greatly limit the number of threads.

Comment: regarding: `pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;`  The `return` statement will never be executed because the call to `pthread_exit()` will have already exited the thread

Comment: `The proper way to initialize a pthread_mutex_t` - initializing a mutex with `pthread_mutex_init` is equally valid. `so when calling pthread_join(), the code can skip those entries` - no, assuming that "0" has a special meaning about `pthread_t` and it has a special meaning in `pthread_join` is just not portable and assumes something about the implementation. `pthread_t` is any abstract type that is used to identify a thread and [the specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/systypes.h.html) doesn't say anything more. To be portable, just use another array of bools.

Comment: @user3629249 regarding the `#define` this code was only to demonstrate a point and it was not intended to be extendable nor maintainable. and regarding the `return` at the end of the function I added it because if you do not return a value in a non void function the C compiler will issue a warning and since I have the compiler flag -Werror my code would not compile. do you suggest any other alternatives ?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: `pthread_create` does not report anything meaningul in `errno`. Its error status is its return value.

Comment: @KamilCuk, the `pthread_t` value is very similar to a PID,  I.E. it will NEVER be 0.

Comment: No, `pthread_t` is not similar to values representing pid. Posix says that `pid_t` type shall be signed integer type. There is no such constrain given for `pthread_t`.

Comment: @yxor, there is NO function in the posted code that doesn't properly exit, with a value (NULL is a value).   Your expected to post code that represents what your actually using.  Comments are for requesting further info and to suggest improvements.  The `OT:` means the comment is not a fix to your problem, but rather a suggestion on a way to improve the code

Comment: @KamilCuk,  Suggest reading the source code for `pthread_create()` (and quit bugging me about inconsequential details)

Comment: The source does not matter. The posix specification matters. The implementation of pthread_create is up to the specification, not the other way round. There are many implementations: [glibc](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/nptl/pthread_create.c#L632) [exxpressif](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/pthread/pthread.c#L217) [uclibc](https://github.com/hwoarang/uClibc/blob/master-metag/libpthread/nptl/pthread_create.c#L431) [cygwin](https://github.com/Alexpux/Cygwin/blob/master/winsup/cygwin/pthread.cc#L18)

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE It probably depends on the implementation.  "an error number shall be returned to indicate the error" isn't exactly what I would call tightly-specified.  At least the `errno` specifications provide some detail.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: No, it's very clearly specified. What documentation are you looking at?

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE POSIX:  https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_create.html

Comment: @AndrewHenle: That's the old version but little is changed. You have to read ERRORS immediately below. Compare with other functions specified to return -1 or a negative value and set `errno`.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. properly checks for errors
3. properly initializes the mutex
4. performs the desired functionality
5. results in an output of 0

Note: function: `pthread_mutex_init()` is a valid function, but a initial value of `NULL` is not valid

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int num = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* add(void* args)
{
    int sign = *(int*) args;

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        num += sign;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


int main( void )
{
    pthread_t pool[1000];
    int plus = +1;
    int minus = -1;


    for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        if( pthread_create(&pool[i], NULL, add, &plus) != 0 )
        {
            perror( "pthread_create failed" );
            pool[i] = 0;
        }


    for(int i = 500; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        if( pthread_create(&pool[i], NULL, add, &minus) != 0 )
        {
            perror( "pthread-create failed" );
            pool[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        if( pool[i] )
        {
            pthread_join(pool[i], NULL);
        }
    }

    printf("%d", num);
    return 0;
}
```

a run of the proposed code, on linux, results in:

```
0
```

Comment: `pool[i] = 0;` - I don't think it's sane to assume `pthread_t` is a numeric type.

Comment: If your really worried about the type then use: `pool[i] = (pthread_t)0;`

Comment: Casting a numeric value to a type doesn't change anything in this context. [pthread_t](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/compat/win32/pthread.h#L51) can be anything. It just "happens" to be a arithmetic type in glibc.

Comment: this code does not compile with the flags -Wall and -Werror.
`main.c: In function 'add':
main.c:20:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
 }
 ^
cc1.exe: all warnings being treated as errors`

Comment: can you modify it so I do not get this warning ?

Comment: Also on my machine your code has the same effect as the code I posted. I think the issue is related to minGW and I discussed it further in the comments on the question.

Comment: I compile my answer with: *gcc    -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11  -c "untitled2.c"*  and it shows no errors nor warnings.   This indicates there is something wrong with your install/configuration of `mingw`

Comment: you can replace: *perror( "pthread-create failed" );* with *fprintf( stderr,   "pthread-create failed\n" );*

Comment: that is not related to the warning im getting, @user3629249 as you can clearly see its talking about the absence of a return statement in the add function.

Comment: @yxor,  This is the return statement in the thread function: `add()`  `pthread_exit(NULL);`   Why is your compiler not recognizing that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206676/discussion-between-yxor-and-user3629249).